# Confused about this code. Dijkstra's Algorithm

Tags: java

Re edit: Sorry if I pasted the code to pastebin. And I don't know that you guys could close a question so fast.

So i was modifying the code and after finishing I have no idea why what I did wrong because:

> Everytime I add a entry in the map file It instead of calculating the the path It returns infinity on the eigth node: It doesnt give a stack trace but instead it throws:

```
Distance to Mandurriao: 0.0
Path: [Mandurriao]
Distance to Jaro: 79.0
Path: [Mandurriao, Jaro]
Distance to Iloilo: 118.0
Path: [Mandurriao, Jaro, Iloilo]
Distance to Leganes: 182.0
Path: [Mandurriao, Jaro, Leganes]
Distance to Tagbak: 81.0
Path: [Mandurriao, Tagbak]
Distance to Derp: 214.0
Path: [Mandurriao, Tagbak, Derp]
Distance to Herp: 305.0
Path: [Mandurriao, Tagbak, Derp, Herp]
Distance to Tugigarao: Infinity
Path: [Tugigarao]
```

> And everytime I make my map file less than 7 nodes it gives me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Dijkstra.search(Dijkstra.java:81)
        at Dijkstra.main(Dijkstra.java:132)
```

I'm a complete java noob, and I have been only making java code like a day ago.

So here's the code:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>
{
    public final String name;
    public Edge[] adjacencies;
    public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    public Vertex previous;
    public Vertex(String argName) { name = argName; }
    public String toString() { return name; }
    public int compareTo(Vertex other)
    {
        return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
    }

}


class Edge
{
    public final Vertex target;
    public final double weight;
    public Edge(Vertex argTarget, double argWeight)
    { target = argTarget; weight = argWeight; }
}



public class Dijkstra
{


    public static void computePaths(Vertex source)
    {
        source.minDistance = 0.;
        PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
    vertexQueue.add(source);

    while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
        Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();

            // Visit each edge exiting u
            for (Edge e : u.adjacencies)
            {
                Vertex v = e.target;
                double weight = e.weight;
                double distanceThroughU = u.minDistance + weight;
        if (distanceThroughU < v.minDistance) {
            vertexQueue.remove(v);

            v.minDistance = distanceThroughU ;
            v.previous = u;
            vertexQueue.add(v);
        }
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target)
    {
        List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous)
            path.add(vertex);

        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
    }




     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static int search(String [ ] numbers, String key)
    {
           for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++)
          {
               if ( numbers[index].equals(key) )
                     return index;  //We found it!!!
          }
         // If we get to the end of the loop, a value has not yet
         // been returned.  We did not find the key in this array.
         return -1;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int MapLength = 0;
        Vertex[] v = new Vertex[100];
        String[] names = new String[100];
        System.out.println("Initalized");
        try {
            int i = 0;
            System.out.println("Initalized[0]");
            FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream("f:\\map2.txt");
            System.out.println("Initalized[1]");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fStream));
            System.out.println("Initalized[2]");
            while (in.ready()) {
                String parsed = "";
                parsed = in.readLine();
                String[] t = parsed.split(">");
                if(t[0].equals("v")){
                    System.out.println("Added>" + parsed);
                    v[i] = new Vertex(t[1]);
                    names[i] = t[1];
                    i++;
                    MapLength = i;
                    }

                if(t[0].equals("e")){
                    System.out.println("Initalized[3]");
                    int a;
                    int weight;
                    int ii = 0;

                    System.out.println("Initalized[4]." + t[1]);
                    String[] container = t[1].split("-");
                    System.out.println("Initalized[5]." + container);

                    Edge[] temp = new Edge[(container.length - 1) / 2];


                    for(a = 1; a < container.length; a +=2 ){
                        System.out.println("Initalized[6]." + names[search( names , container[ a ] )] + "...." + Integer.parseInt(container[ a + 1 ]));
                        temp[ii] = new Edge(v[ search( names , container[ a ] ) ], Integer.parseInt(container[ a + 1 ]));
                        ii++;
                        }
                    //System.out.println("Debug@LineCurrentNumberSearch: " +  search( names , container[ a ] ) );
                    v[ search( names , container[ 0 ] ) ].adjacencies = temp;


                    }


            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File input error" + e);
            }

/*
    v[0] = new Vertex("Harrisburg");
    v[1] = new Vertex("Baltimore");
    v[2] = new Vertex("Washington");
    v[3] = new Vertex("Philadelphia");
    v[4] = new Vertex("Binghamton");
    v[5] = new Vertex("Allentown");
    v[6] = new Vertex("New York");



    v[0].adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v[1],  79.83), new Edge(v[5],  81.15) };

    v[1].adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v[0],  79.75),
                                 new Edge(v[2],  39.42),
                                 new Edge(v[3], 103.00) };
    v[2].adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v[1],  38.65) };
    v[3].adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v[1], 102.53),
                                 new Edge(v[5],  61.44),
                                 new Edge(v[6],  96.79) };
    v[4].adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v[5], 133.04) };
    v[5].adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v[0],  81.77),
                                 new Edge(v[3],  62.05),
                                 new Edge(v[4], 134.47),
                                 new Edge(v[6],  91.63) };
    v[6].adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v[3],  97.24),
                                 new Edge(v[5],  87.94) };
*/

    Vertex[] vertices = new Vertex[MapLength];
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < MapLength; j++){
        vertices[j] = v[j];
        }

        computePaths(v[0]);
        for (Vertex a : vertices)
    {
        System.out.println("Distance to " + a + ": " + a.minDistance);
        List<Vertex> path = getShortestPathTo(a);
        System.out.println("Path: " + path);
    }
    }
}
```

and here's the map file:

```
v>Mandurriao
v>Jaro
v>Iloilo
v>Leganes
v>Tagbak
v>Derp
v>Herp
v>Tugigarao
e>Mandurriao-Jaro-79-Tagbak-81
e>Jaro-Mandurriao-79-Iloilo-39-Leganes-103
e>Iloilo-Jaro-38
e>Leganes-Jaro-102-Tagbak-61-Derp-69
e>Tagbak-Derp-133
e>Derp-Mandurriao-81-Leganes-62-Tagbak-134-Herp-91
e>Herp-Leganes-97-Derp-87
e>Tugigarao-Herp-100
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input file contains the following entry:

```
v>Mandurriao
v>Jaro
v>Iloilo
v>Leganes
v>Tagbak
v>Derp
e>Mandurriao-Jaro-79-Tagbak-81
e>Jaro-Mandurriao-79-Iloilo-39-Leganes-103
e>Iloilo-Jaro-38
e>Leganes-Jaro-102-Tagbak-61-Derp-69
e>Tagbak-Derp-133
```

The vertex "Derp" does not have any adjacent vertices, hence u.adjacency is null, causing the null pointer exception for entries less than 7.

Comment: I see. So, I guess it was on my part on why I'm wrong. But Now the question is. Why does it compute to infinity when adding more than seven entries?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it and I posted it why it's calculating it to infinity. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Ok just to show anyone if somehow some Googlers stumbled upon here.

The reason why it counted to infinity is that there are no nodes that is referencing the 'Tugigarao' vertex therefore shows no path to it. As you might say, you can come out of the vertex but you can't come in since there's no reference or edge.